# Reset Make's dependency dates

Tags: date, makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I set my computer's date to 1 year in the future, make a change to `main.c`, and recompile my project with `make`.

I set my computer's date back to the real date, however `make` now thinks that the file was last modified 1 year in the future.

I can no longer make a change to `main.c` and have `make` recognize it, unless I set my date to the future.

Is there a way to reset `make`'s dependency dates?

Comment: Make uses dates of modification of files. You can alter them using your file manager or touch command (touch -t 20141130 your_file)

Comment: Do you want to reset the modification time of `main.c` to now+(one year), or the modification time of `main` to now-(one minute)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From backup. Other than that, you can date all files to the same timestamp, e.g. the time now.

On a Unix-like system (such as Linux or Cygwin), this command will do that for you (after you have `cd`ed to the top of the build tree):

```
find . -type f | xargs -d '\n' touch
```

If you want to be 100% all files will have the same timestamp, do

```
now=`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s`; find . -type f | xargs -d '\n' touch --date="$now"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I explained myself well enough. Because I am saving in the present, I am already changing the file's timestamps to the present. The problem is that `make` then decides that the files I have modified have not been modified because the time has gone backwards.

Comment: Do it after you have gone backwards.

Comment: Your answer just explains how to change the timestamp of a file. I am not interested in this. I want to reset the internal dates that Make uses to determine whether a file has been modified or not.

Comment: @Jimmay There is no such thing as "the internal dates that Makes uses". The very first comment on your question (by [frp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217637/reset-makes-dependency-dates#comment42915307_27217637)) says as much: "Make uses dates of modification of files". There's nothing more to it. Make uses the last modification time of a prerequisite and the last modification time of a target and compares them. There is no 
"*internal* date".